# Test if function pointer can be converted to object pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, type-conversion

[[expr.reinterpret.cast]#8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#8) says:

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported.

I am writing a library. Can I determine somehow, whether in the current compiler it is supported? And in which direction?

Comment: Instead of doing something that may or may not be supported, why not go another way that all compilers support?

Comment: What is the underlying problem you need to solve? What would this knowledge do for your library that can't be done otherwise?

Comment: Generally libraries will have looked at the documentation of well known compilers, and determine which of those is in use by what it is known to `#define`

Comment: It's supported on any compiler targeting a posix system (where these conversions are required to work by the posix standard).

Comment: Use preprocessor directives. I know `__GNUC__ > 4` supports it.

Comment: I think you'll just have to read the docs for each compiler/platform you want to support, then test for each of those compilers using their respective predefined macros, like `__GNUC__` or `_MSC_VER`.

Comment: How about `sizeof(void(*)()) == sizeof(void*)` as a test? If it's `true`, does that mean, that I can safely convert one to the other and vice versa?

Comment: *If it's true, does that mean, that I can safely convert one to the other and vice versa?*  Unfortunately, no.  Not a *carte blanch* guarantee.  It does mean that it **might** be convertible... which is still a platform and compiler implementation detail.  If that is `false`, I think that means that it is a sure thing that it is **not** convertible.

Comment: How will you use this information?

Comment: If the cast compiles, then it's supported. Use any known technique (SFINAE or concepts) to check.